# Qt 5.3.2 / Set minimum size of a QToolBox item

Tags: qt, qt5

Okay so my program is basically a set of scripts I’d like to edit/create with a nice GUI written in C++ with… Qt !
A script is an ensemble of steps such as “sql query” “send mail”, and so on and so forth…

It looks like this :
[image: Normal use]

Okay, everything is fine, but when I add a lot of steps (which I will CERTAINLY do later), it looks like this :
[image: Too much steps makes it impossible to read]

The whole QToolBox is inside a QScrollArea (tried to show it in screenshot).

What do I have to do in order to specify to a QToolBox item its minimum height depending on the size of the widget inside ?
Thanks a lot !

EDIT : Don’t pay attention to the item’s content on my screenshot they are all the same for the moment.

EDIT: I just tried with the strategy found [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2305) (setting parent and grand parent a minimum height) but it’s not working the way I want : my item’s widget is indeed bigger, but I still have the same result as my second picture when I have a lot of items.

EDIT: Trying @Klathzazt solution ended up in this strange behavior
[Compressed tabs http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/294374Capturedcran20141107162044.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/294374Capturedcran20141107162044.png)

Answer (score 0):

A similar discussion can be found here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/2305

Personally I didn't go with the custom page as discussed in that thread.

What I tried is: set the minimum height of the toolbox to a sufficiently large value. This way each of the pages can expand to the full size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that did not went well. By setting for instance `m_toolBox->setMinimumHeight(500);` I ended up with this result for a lot of tabs [link](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/294374Capturedcran20141107162044.png)...

With no particular settings, tabs in a toolbox will keep a certain minimum height. Is this value contained in a variable somewhere ? I have the feeling I just have to find it.

Comment: @nsierra- If you haven't, try the solution I mentioned in the thread. That seemed like the most correct approach.